# import .dump postgresql backup?

Tags: database, postgresql, import, dump

I'm new to postgresql. We have weekly datadumps which are stored with a `.dump` extension. I want to import one of these in order to interact with the data locally on my machine. I tried with `pgAdmin` but that apparently only imports `.json` files, and then i tried with a free trial of `tableplus`, but I still can't figure it out there. Does anyone know what approach I should use to achieve this?

Many thanks!

Comment: People can name files whatever they want, the extension doesn't tell us anything.  What is inside the file?

Comment: 1) How are the weekly data dumps created? 2) `pgAdmin` works with more then `json` files. That being said I would use other tools.